# Swift 3 Triggered Segue with variable

Tags: swift3

I have a tableview with static cells - a menu.

Articles

Reading List

etc...

The cells are linked to other storyboards and called by a Triggered Segue Show

I want to use the same view controller for Articles and Reading List, but just change my query to the DB.

How can I tell the view controller which tableviewcell loaded it?

Answer (score 0):

If your tableview is static (having fixed number of each style cell), you can simply try `indexPath`.If your tableview is dynamic, you can divide menu, articles, reading list into different `UITableViewCell` classes, and then distinguish them by checking cell's class

Comment: So I do need some code to do this then, not just using what Storyboard provides?

Comment: Your can carry it out mainly in code,while using Storyboard to do some layout work. [Here](https://github.com/Millionaryearl/Stack-Overflow/tree/master/TableViewNavigation) is a demo